# Highlight a Range using Javascript is not Working

Tags: javascript, html, uiwebview, range

The below code to highlight a Range fails. [Try out the code.](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammedmt/zjd3d7ud/)

```
function rangeFromString(rangeString)
{
     var rangeStringSplit = rangeString.split(/\|/g);
     var range = document.createRange();
     var node = document.evaluate(rangeStringSplit[0], document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
     range.setStart(node, Number(rangeStringSplit[1]));
     node = document.evaluate(rangeStringSplit[2], document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
     range.setEnd(node, Number(rangeStringSplit[3]));
     console.log(range);
     return range;
}

function highlightRangeString(rangeString,color)
{
     if (rangeString != null)
     {
          var range = rangeFromString(rangeString);
          console.log(range);

          var sel = window.getSelection();
          sel.removeAllRanges();

          sel.addRange(range);
          document.designMode = "on";
          document.execCommand("hiliteColor", false, "#"+color);
          sel.removeAllRanges();
          document.designMode = "off";
     }
}
```

I have tried the below code,

```
highlightRangeString("/HTML[1]/BODY[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[2]/P[1]/SPAN[1]/text()[1]|2|/HTML[1]/BODY[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[2]/P[1]/SPAN[1]/text()[1]|20", "ff0000");
```

What is wrong with this code ?

How I can select and apply highlighting to a Range ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the characters you're trying to highlight are white space characters within the text node and are collapsed in the rendered HTML, hence a selection containing them is also collapsed. If you remove the line break and indentation inside the `<span>` element containing the text, it will work as you expect.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zjd3d7ud/5/